# Getting list of EMR Release labels via Amazon API

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, elastic-map-reduce

I need to receive the list of available EMR Release labels in order to run my Java application which starts an EC2 instance and executes a hadoop job. The main problem here that EMR Release labels are specific for each region and I need to get this list dynamically. The sample of the code used in my application:

```
runJobFlowRequest.setReleaseLabel( "emr-4.8.0" );
```

Does anyone have an idea where I could obtain this list of Release labels programmatically via Amazon API in order to use it in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think we have any API exposed to get this list programatically. Usually most regions will have same release labels and  EMR Console should show the most updated list for a specific region.

You can also see the list on the documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-relguide-links.html

Comment: Okay, I've got it. Thanks for your reply